# Pricing of a derivative using Risk Neutral Valuation.

Tags: option-pricing, derivatives, lognormal

I am new to option pricing and following problem came up that I don't understand how to handle.

A derivative will pay out dollar amount equal to $$\frac1T\ln \frac{S_T}{S_0}$$ at maturity, where $S_T$ is distributed log-normally, and the expected return is $\mu$ and volatility is $\sigma$ and $T$ is the time. **So what is the price of the derivative using risk neutral valuation.**.

I know I have to use a stock and a derivative to make a risk neutral portfolio, but not really sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the risk-neutral probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$, the logarithmic return is normally distributed with

\begin{equation}
\ln \left( \frac{S_T}{S_0} \right) \sim \mathcal{N} \left( \left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) T, \sigma^2 T \right).
\end{equation}

Thus,

\begin{eqnarray}
V_0 & = & \frac{1}{T} e^{-r T} \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q} \left[ \ln \left( \frac{S_T}{S_0} \right) \right]\\
& = & e^{-r T} \left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right).
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: In Hull the expression uses $\sigma$ and not $\sigma^2$ and $\mu$ instead of $r$. Also what you did here seems like you calculated the present value of the expected return we will get in the future. Can you clarify these two things?

Comment: 1) Under the risk-neutral probability measure, the expected return on the stock is $r$ not $\mu$. 2) If Hull has a $\sigma$ in the final expression, then this is wrong. 3) Discounting because $\left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right)$ is the expected payoff at time $T$ while you want the present value.

Comment: checked hull, the expression is correct, also i am assuming that second term in the expression of normal distribution is the variance and not the standard deviation.

Comment: Yes - in my case this is the variance. From what I’ve seen, this is the more common notation though you do indeed find both.